# In the scroll of the UWP, want to fix both the header of rows and columns as EXCEL

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

all.

Currently, we are creating a table in the UWP (Universal Windows platform) application.
Implementation method as in the following sample, has been achieved by placing the longitudinal direction of the ItemsControl in the lateral direction ItemsControl.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="ColumnList">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="RowHeaderList">
            <Button Content="*" />
            <Button Content="1" />
            <Button Content="2" />
            <Button Content="3" />
        </ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="ColumnA_Cells">
            <Button Content="A" />
            <TextBox Text="A1" />
            <TextBox Text="A2" />
            <TextBox Text="A3" />
        </ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="ColumnB_Cells">
            <Button Content="B" />
            <TextBox Text="B1" />
            <TextBox Text="B2" />
            <TextBox Text="B3" />
        </ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="ColumnC_Cells">
            <Button Content="C" />
            <TextBox Text="C1" />
            <TextBox Text="C2" />
            <TextBox Text="C3" />
        </ItemsControl>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

※ fact is bound to the ItemsSource but was omitted for simplification of the sample code.

Any of the header content to one element eyes of each ItemsControl, matrix either header fixed by using the ItemsControl that was put in the ScrollViewer to a two-element second is the possible, I do not know how to secure both of the header.
EXCEL of as row header and whether it would be possible, but I want to control as follows: the column header.

- Line header: the vertical scrolling of the table to follow, when the horizontal scroll is fixed.
- Column header: The side-scrolling of the table to follow, when the vertical scroll is fixed.

It survives and can receive advice alone direction.
Thank you.